# Jekyll - select pages with certain key in the front matter

Tags: for-loop, conditional-statements, jekyll, liquid

I have a website made with Jekyll and the navigation bar code looks like this:

```html
{% for my_page in site.pages %}
  {% if my_page.title %}
    {% if my_page.lang == page.lang  %}
      <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ my_page.title }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

this works fine, but when I tried to obtain the same result using the `where_exp` filter I couldn't.

```html
{% assign lang_pages = site.pages | where_exp: "item", "item.title" | where: "lang", page.lang %}

{% for my_page in lang_pages %}
  <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ my_page.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The `where:"lang",page.lang` filter works fine, but I get a lot of empty space for the pages without title, that aren't correctly filtered. I have also tried the following filters and none of them works:

- `where_exp: "item", "item.title != nil"`
- `where_exp: "item", "item.title != empty"`
- `where_exp: "item", "item.title != '' "`
- `where_exp: "item", "item contains 'title' "`
- `where: "title"` - (This appears in the Liquid documentation and it doesn't even compile)

The only workaround I can think of is to manually add `title: nil` to all the pages that shouldn't be included, but it doesn't seem worth it. **Is there a way to select only pages that have certain key in their front matter**?

Neither in the [documentation of Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#where-expression) nor in the [documentation of Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/) I have found useful information regarding this.